# Loop variables through python urls on a list

Tags: python, loops, url

I can get one stock ticker into my URL...but how do I create a list and loop through the URL. Please see a failed attempt...it's for a tweepy project i'm fiddling with. Mostly worried about getting through multiple urls.

```
ticker=["AAPL","XOM"]
For i < len(ticker):


    responeData = requests.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol="+str(ticker[i])+"&apikey=XXXXXX")
    symbol = str(responeData.json()['Meta Data']['2. Symbol'])
    refresh = str(responeData.json()['Meta Data']['3. Last Refreshed'])
    checkclose = str(responeData.json()['Time Series (Daily)'])
    close=str(responeData.json()['Time Series (Daily)'][refresh]['4. close'])


    api.update_status(status=symbol+' '+refresh+' Close Price: $'+close)
```

Comment: Well, first, your `for` loop is syntactically invalid...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate your list.

```
tickers=["AAPL","XOM"]
for ticker in tickers:

    responeData = requests.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol="+ticker+"&apikey=XXXXXX")
    symbol = str(responeData.json()['Meta Data']['2. Symbol'])
    refresh = str(responeData.json()['Meta Data']['3. Last Refreshed'])
    checkclose = str(responeData.json()['Time Series (Daily)'])
    close=str(responeData.json()['Time Series (Daily)'][refresh]['4. close'])

    api.update_status(status=symbol+' '+refresh+' Close Price: $'+close)
```